# Filtering messages to unread and read rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, haml, mailboxer

I want to filter my messages in the website to read and unread. when i click to the unread button there must be just unread messages and this should work as well as reads. I use rails to make this.

In this code i get "param is missing or the value is empty: mailboxer_message" error

index.html.haml

```
  = button_to "Read", messages_path(unread: 1), class: 'btn btn-success'
  = button_to "Unread", messages_path(unread: 0), class: 'btn btn-success'
```

messages.controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        add_breadcrumb "Inbox", :messages_path
        @messages = current_admin.mailbox.inbox.order('updated_at DESC')
        if params[:unread] == 1
          @messages = mailbox.inbox(:unread => true)
        elsif params[:unread] == 0
          @messages = mailbox.inbox(:unread => false)
        end
      end
       .......
      def message_params
        params.require(:mailboxer_message).permit(:conversation_id, :body, :attachment, :recipients, :subject, :unread)
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

`button_to` set `method` to `POST` at default. You can change it by `method`. Then you can pass parameters by `params`.

```
= button_to "Read", messages_path, class: 'btn btn-success', method: :get, params: { unread: 1 }
= button_to "Unread", messages_path, class: 'btn btn-success', method: :get, params: { unread: 0 }
```

Comment: i think i can't change unread params because when i click on the unread or read i get "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error